# Library for finding words similar to those in dictionary

Tags: python, nlp

I've created a set of words and their synonyms using WordNet, so that when the user inputs 'creature' it returns Animal. What I would like to do next is match words that are not synonyms/synsets like 'dog' to Animal. Is there a library for this? Please see below for my code:

```
thisdict ={  "Animal",  "Metal",  "Car"}

syns = {w : [] for w in thisdict}
for k, v in syns.items():
    for synset in wordnet.synsets(k):
        for lemma in synset.lemmas():
            if not k.lower() == lemma.name(): 
                syns[k].append(lemma.name())

def synonyms(syns):
    for key in thisdict:
        print(' '.join(syns[key])+'\n') 
synonyms(syns)
```

Output:

```
'animate_being', 'beast', 'brute', 'creature', 'fauna', 'carnal', 'fleshly', 'sensual'
```

My desired output:

```
'dog', 'cat', etc..
```

Comment: `thisdict`, as you have it defined, is *not* a dictionary, but a set.

Comment: I suggest you to refer [SpaCy](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/276#issuecomment-188197344)

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look